# (tornadio2) failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, tornado

when I run my code on my pc and try to connect socket with my index.html on localhost no problem but when I try to run my code on server and try to connect socket with index.html(it locate on my pc) I get :

```
Router <tornadio2.session.ConnectionInfo object at 0x7f7bfc5fac10>
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /socket.io/1/
DEBUG:root:Initializing websocket handler.
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /socket.io/1/websocket/c0532cea9001408c50a9c854f4bce5d8
```

and after that it switch protocal to xhr-polling but I want to use websocket.

```
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/62f9b31662c984201685a830c764765e
DEBUG:root:Initializing xhr-polling transport.
DEBUG:root:>>> 1::/socket
DEBUG:root:<<< 1::/socket
DEBUG:root:<<< 3::/socket:connected!
```

what can I do to fix that problem ?

Comment: Can you supply the code you're running

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SeyitOzanOzdil/0329ba2c9ebc9faa090e here is on_open and on_close part of Socket Connection class

Comment: and this one my html https://gist.github.com/SeyitOzanOzdil/d79881ede70ebb159740 I open this on my pc.

Answer (score 21):

The html must be loaded from the same server as the websocket unless you override check_origin to allow cross-origin access: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.check_origin

Answer (score -6):

Solved it. for tornadio2 users you have to do that :

add this code to persistent.py(it locate in tornadio2)

```
def check_origin(self, origin):
    return True
```

Comment: It will be polite to accept right answer provided above

Comment: This answer correct in your use case but it could be very unsecure without an explanation. Please accept the right answer.